# The speed of throwing an object horizontally such that it is in orbit around the Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, earth, speed

The question is given that for every 3,570 meters you walk , the Earth curves downward by 1 meter. 
The time it takes an object to fall from a height h is 
t = sqrt(2h/g), where t is in seconds, h is in meters, g is 9.8m/s^2
 * Air resistance is ignored.

First I have calculated the time it takes an object to fall from a height of 1 meter is t = sqrt(2(1)/9.8) = 0.45175 second

So for the speed that to throw an object horizontally, so that they are in orbit around the earth, would it be v = d/t and v = 3570/0.45175 = 7902.6 m/s? 
is it make sense?

Comment: I dont think thats correct because you linked horizontal and vertical components in your first paragraph which you are not suppose to do. Vertical and horizontal velocities of an object are independent of each other. Also orbital velocity depends on your height above Earth. The higher you go the lower the velocity required because the gravitational force is lower.

Comment: All that you seem to be asking is "Check my work." The site policy for such exercises is that you need to **ask about a specific physics concept**.

Comment: @sammygerbil: to be fair I think the OP is trying to understand the concept behind the calculation. It isn't just a matter of checking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your result is correct, and you have indeed understood the problem correctly.

We normally do this calculation differently. For an object in a circular orbit with a radius $r$ at an orbital velocity $v$ the centripetal acceleration is:

$$ a_c = \frac{v^2}{r} $$

For a stable circular orbit round the Earth the centripetal acceleration has to be the same as the gravtitational acceleration:

$$ a_g = \frac{GM}{r^2} $$

where $G$ is the gravitational contant and $M$ is the mass of the Earth. If we set $a_c = a_g$ we get:

$$ \frac{v^2}{r} = \frac{GM}{r^2} $$

And this rearranges to:

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}} \tag{1} $$

You are calculating what the orbital velocity would be at the Earth's surface, so we need to set $r$ equal to the radius of the Earth, which is $r=6.371 \times 10^6$ m. If I put this into equation (1) I get:

$$ v \approx 7900 \,\text{ms}^{-1} $$

And this matches your answer.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the clear explanation! Although I have seen your formula, my professor didn't mention this (probably because it's just an exploration of space class). The thing I am struggling with is I cannot interpret my way of calculating the speed - I did that just because I know v = d/t and d=3570 and t = 0.45s are the two numbers seem to fit in the formula . I know if I throw the object horizontally fast enough so it goes 3570m before it falls 1m then it orbits around Eart. How can the distance 3570m and the time it takes the object falls 1m put together to get the orbital velocity?

Comment: @musicbear: have a look at [the Wikipedia article on Newton's cannonball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_cannonball) to get a feel for what is going on here.